# How can I find the element that caused another element to fire the focusout event?

Tags: javascript

i bind an eventhandler to the focusout-event of my text-inputfield.
this handler hides a div with some searchresults as soon as the inputfield losts its focus.

following my markup and a screenshot of the situation:

```
<li class="search">
    <input type="text" id="searchbox" />
    <div id="results">
        <ol>
            <li>...</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</li>
```

[image]

when the user clicks on a item in the searchresults now, the inputfield fires the focusout event as desired.
i expected to be able extracting the element which gets the focus as next out of the eventobject. unfortunatly this seems not to be possible since only (some) mouse-events fill in the relatedTarget-property of the event.

is there any easy way to get the element which gains focus next?

Answer (score 2):

Would this help you? http://plugins.jquery.com/project/focused

Not in older browsers, but there's document.activeElement too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.activeElement

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! it seems that document.activeElement is not already filled in with the latest focused element when focusout is fired. further i wasnt able to get livequery running (seems to be a dependency of the focus-plugin above) ... a fellow student suggested to solve the problem with a mouse-listener... i'll give that a try once

Comment: WOW.  So there's no way to find out, while inside the JavaScript focusout event, what's getting the focus?  That pretty much makes it impossible to properly handle a focusout event, specifically if you want to avoid the default behavior if a sibling element receives the focus.