# Get the element that triggered focusout event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i find, what element triggerd focusout event ?

I mean, if i'm focused on some text box, and i click on some element for example div with name (results)), i wan't to get that div attributes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the element that caused another element to fire the focusout event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548627/how-can-i-find-the-element-that-caused-another-element-to-fire-the-focusout-even)

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('body').find('*').bind('focusin click', function () {
                var obj = $(this);
                $('#ResultAttr').text('id: ' + obj.attr('id') + ', data-id:' + obj.attr('data-id') + ', data-test:' + obj.data('test'));
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="ResultAttr"></span><br />
    <input type="text" id="tbTest" data-id="3" data-test="88" />
    <div id="divTest" data-id="2" data-test="34">
        Test
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: God, how inefficient is `$('body').find('*')`?!